# Stripe: Sending Email One Day Before Subscription Trial Ends Using API

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

According to the documentation, I only found an event to send an email three days before the subscription trial ends. However, I couldn't find one to send an email one day before. Is there any way to achieve this using APIs?

```
webook
customer.subscription.trial_will_end    

description
Sent three days before the trial period ends. If the trial is less than 3 days, this event is triggered.    

use case
Configure the subscription to automatically send an email to your customer 3 days before the trial period ends.
```

I wasn't able to find a webhook event or any workaround to address it.

Comment: The Subscription object has a [trial_will_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-trial_end) timestamp. You could save that to your DB and then run a cron job at a certain time each day to send an email to customers whose trial is ending